# Redundant conditional operator

Tags: verilog

I have come across this coding style a few times in verilog code:

```
input enable;
input [1:0] mode;
wire mode_enable;

assign mode_enable = ( enable & (mode == 2'b00) ) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
```

What is the purpose of the conditional operator here? It seems redundant and confusing since I think that this gives the exact same result:

```
assign mode_enable = ( enable & (mode == 2'b00) );
```

Does this somehow help with simulation, or guide synthesis?

Comment: what are the sizes of b and c?

Comment: Good question. This is a simplified version of what I saw, but I think b and c were both expressions that evaluated to single bits. I need to go find the code to see.

Comment: Since many have pointed out that it is not redundant if we are dealing with multi-bit signals, I have adjusted the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To updated question:

The only difference between `( enable & (mode == 2'b00) )` and `( enable & (mode == 2'b00) ) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0` is the latter infers a mux at synthesis. The synthesis may even optimize out the mux.

Reason the RLT designer my want to have a mux:

1. The mux could have a more desirable fan-out load driver.
2. Purposely injecting delay for glitch filtering and/or balancing of logic propagation delay.
3. For IC design it can make a manual ECO easier, swapping the one input with another net.

The above reasons are pointless 98% of the time with a proper tools. A good synthesis and timing analysis tool will handle reasons 1 and 2. Add a good ECO tool and the third point is covered. The other 2% is mostly for the rare case you expect do an ECO, then forcing the mux makes the final output location and load more predictable.

---

To original question:

It is redundant only if  `b` and `c` are single bit. If they are multiple bits width, then equation cannot be simplified. `a` will be 1 if `b` and `c` both have a 1 values on the same bit indexes.

For example, assume `b` and `c` are 2 bits wide: (`assign a = (b & c) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0`)

- `b`=2 `c`=3, `a` will be 1 because `b & c`=2
- `b`=2 `c`=1, `a` will be 0 because `b & c`=0

Comment: So, to summarize: this is not something I would want to do unless I had a really good reason.  I would have asked the guy who wrote the code, but he doesn't work here any more. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This does not give the same result if the size of all of `a`, `b`, and `c` are not 1:

```
assign a = b & c;
```

But this is the same:

```
assign a = b && c;
```